# Track push notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-push-notification

I have a android library project that handles the push notification for the application. I have to track the different user actions upon receiving the notification. I get events like notification received, rendered etc, but Is there any way to track push notification click in android?

Comment: can you say what do you want to do?

Comment: I need to track the Push notification click event. Everytime user clicks and opens on a notification on system tray i need to record it internally in the library to keep track